# Pandas: How to append a dataframe to itself if .append has been deprecated?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-lab

[Learn Data Sci: Pandas A Complete Tutorial](https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-pandas-tutorial-complete-introduction-for-beginners/)

I am following this tutorial to learn some basic Python for data analysis and I'm starting to realize it may be dated. There is a section where it copies and appends rows from an existing dataframe to itself in order to produce some duplicates that we later dedupe. Unfortunately, the tutorial code is failing when I try to append the dataframe to itself... After some googling, I noticed that .append may have been deprecated from the Pandas API... Is there a workaround for this so I can simply move on with the rest of the tutorial?

## Handling duplicates

This dataset does not have duplicate rows, but it is always important to verify you aren't aggregating duplicate rows.

To demonstrate, let's simply just double up our movies DataFrame by appending it to itself:

```
temp_df = movies_df.append(movies_df)

temp_df.shape
OUT:
(2000, 11)

Using append() will return a copy without affecting the original DataFrame. We are capturing this copy in temp so we aren't working with the real data.

Notice call .shape quickly proves our DataFrame rows have doubled.


I've tried searching for a workaround, but have not found the exact same scenario
```

Answer (score 0):

`concat` can be used instead of append:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,2,3]})

df = pd.concat([df,df]).reset_index(drop = True)

print(df)
```

giving:

```
   col1
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     1
4     2
5     3
```